# Get Name of Parent ChoiceField Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have an array of choices which are implemented in my `Field` model like so:

```
CULTIVATIONS = [
    ('Apples', (
        ('willow', 'Willow'),
        ('devil', 'Devil'),
    )),
    ('Cherries', (
        ('samba', 'Samba'),
        ('rita', 'Rita'),
    )),
    ('Peaches', (
        ('zodiac', 'Zodiac'),
        ('astoria', 'Astoria'),
    )),
    ('Nectarines', (
        ('patagonia', 'Patagonia'),
        ('garcima', 'Garcima'),
    )),
]
class Field(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Fields"

    ...
    cultivation = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=CULTIVATIONS, blank=True)
```

If i have a `Field` model I can access `cultivation` like `field.cultivation` .
Question is how do I access the group's name? How to get the `Apples` choice instead of `willow` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a direct way to get the value of the group name based on sub groups from Django. But one of the solution can be a pythonic one like this:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[1][0][0] == 'willow', CULTIVATIONS))[0][0]  # or using next(...) as next example
```

You can use it the view like this:

```
class SomeView(FormView):
    ...
    def get_group(self, subgroup):
       try:
           return next(filter(lambda x: x[1][0][0] == subgroup, CULTIVATIONS))[0]
       except StopIteration:
           return None

    def form_valid(self, form):
        group = self.get_group(form.cleaned_data['cultivation'])
```

Same function can be used in the form as well.

```
class FieldForm(forms.Form):
     ... # including get_group method

     def save(self, commit=False)
       form = super().save(commit)
       group = self.get_group(form.cleaned_data['cultivation'])
       ....
```

Comment: Yeah figured it out also after a while thanks . I was just hoping there would be a more direct way.